# How to install H264 H263 codec with linphone python wrapper

Tags: python, h.264, codec, linphone, linphone-sdk

Any suggestions to use H263/H264 codec with linhpone python wrapper? I see VP8 as the only available codec

I've installed linphone with all codecs and I've tried using linphonec -C command line and I can make video calls without any problem, but using python wrapper I see only VP8 as available codec.